# jsp kendo ui update table, post request

Tags: java, jsp, request, kendo-grid

I followed the tutorial at blogs.teleric.com
so I created a table.

When I click Edit, change some fields after this click Update and have Exception on the server. In doPost() method I checked fields by

```
System.err.println(request.getParameter("ID"));
```

And so on for all 4 fields and in all of them I have null.
But! I also cheked in browser POST request

```
 - Request URL:`http://localhost:8080/FinalTask/Doctor?update`
 - Request Method:POST
 - ...
 - Request Payload: {"id":1,"FIO":"IVAN IVANOV IVANOVICH","category":"surgeon","numPatients":1}
```

Why do HttpServletRequest's parameters are empty?

```
    <kendo:grid name="Doctor" pageable="true">
    <kendo:grid-editable mode="inline" />
    <kendo:dataSource pageSize="5">
        <kendo:dataSource-transport>
            <kendo:dataSource-transport-read url="Doctor"></kendo:dataSource-transport-read>
            <kendo:dataSource-transport-update url="Doctor?update" type="POST" contentType="application/json"></kendo:dataSource-transport-update>
        </kendo:dataSource-transport>
        <kendo:dataSource-schema>
            <kendo:dataSource-schema-model id="id">
                <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-fields>
                    <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="id" type="number">
                        <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field-validation required="true" min="1" />
                    </kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field>
                    <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="FIO" type="string">
                        <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field-validation required="true"/>
                    </kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field>
                    <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="category" type="string">
                        <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field-validation required="true"/>
                    </kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field>
                    <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field name="numPatients" type="number" >
                        <kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field-validation required="true" min="1" />
                    </kendo:dataSource-schema-model-field>
                </kendo:dataSource-schema-model-fields>
            </kendo:dataSource-schema-model>
        </kendo:dataSource-schema>
    </kendo:dataSource>
    <kendo:grid-columns>
        <kendo:grid-column field="id" title="ID" format="{0:n0}"></kendo:grid-column>
        <kendo:grid-column field="FIO" title="Name"></kendo:grid-column>
        <kendo:grid-column field="category" title="Category"></kendo:grid-column>
        <kendo:grid-column field="numPatients" title="Patients number"
            format="{0:n0}"></kendo:grid-column>
        <kendo:grid-column>
            <kendo:grid-column-command>
                <kendo:grid-column-commandItem name="edit"></kendo:grid-column-commandItem>
                <kendo:grid-column-commandItem name="destroy"></kendo:grid-column-commandItem>
            </kendo:grid-column-command>
        </kendo:grid-column>
    </kendo:grid-columns>
</kendo:grid>
```

Comment: see http://demos.telerik.com/jsp-ui/grid/editing-inline check "http://demos.telerik.com/jsp-ui/grid/editing-inline". Here you are using "ID" instead of "id"

Comment: I used this demo this tutorial [link](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/13-03-05/handling_crud_with_the_kendo_ui_jsp_wrappers)
And have this problem. The problem is that `HttpServletRequest request` in doPost() method is emty